# How to create anonymous field with values in oracle select query

Tags: sql, oracle, select-query

I have following select query which returns `KPI_DEF_ID` values.

```
Select KPI_DEF_ID from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID NOT IN (Select KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_STATUS);
```

The query returns the output:

```
KPI_DEF_ID
10001
10002
```

Now i want to modify the select query with anonymous fields `KPI_STATUS_BEFORE` and `KPI_STATUS_NOW` and it contains the values as `'G'`.
The `KPI_DEFINTION` table does not have this columns.The output should something look likes:

```
KPI_DEF_ID    KPI_STATUS_BEFORE    KPI_STATUS_NOW
10001         G                    G
10002         G                    G
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: `Select KPI_DEF_ID, 'G' AS KPI_STATUS_BEFORE, 'G' AS KPI_STATUS_NOW from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID NOT IN (Select KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_STATUS);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is not anonymous columns but *computed* columns (or *derived* columns).  you create those by just specifying the expression in the query:

```
Select 
    KPI_DEF_ID ,
    'G' AS KPI_STATUS_BEFORE,
    'G' AS KPI_STATUS_AFTER
from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION 
WHERE KPI_DEF_ID NOT IN (Select KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_STATUS)
```